# Is it possible to retrieve text files content from a parameter and display in HTML?

Tags: html, jsp

Say I have a product listing with descriptions. Can I store the descriptions in text files and call them by setting a parameter path in web.xml? Is that even possible? Calling txt file extensions?

It may be a stupid question but I have no clue... Would it slow down the app if I host everything in separate files instead of the database?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, very much so; you are referring to `static sites`, which may be pre-generated or may be very simple wrapped by jsp. Take a look at [static site generators](https://staticsitegenerators.net/).